# Plot doesnot change with drop down select

Tags: python, python-3.x, panel, holoviz

I am trying to build an interactive plot for dashboard. The data is in pandas dataframe `state_df`.

```
ty=['Confirmed','Bedridden','Recovered']

def type_tt(need_type):
    need=[]
    need.append(need_type)
    my_df=state_df[state_df.Status.isin(need)]
    my_df=my_df.set_index('Date')
    return my_df


def heat_map(types):
    num=10# 10 day
    my_df=type_tt(types)
    sns.heatmap((my_df.drop('Status',axis=1)).tail(num)[top_14],cmap='Blues', linewidths=0.1)
    #df.style.background_gradient(cmap='Blues')

#heat_map(types_op)
app7=pn.interact(heat_map,types=ty)
app7
```

This gives a drop-down menu with options
[image]

But when I change the option from dropdown menu, the plot doesn't change. 
I tried looking into documentation for linking but nothing works out.

Any leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The most important thing to add here is that your function `heat_map()` needs to `return` your plot. I think that's what is missing.**

It's hard to recreate your example since there is no sample data, but here's an example that works. I've used [hvplot](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Introduction.html) instead of seaborn to create an interactive heatmap.

**Example code:**

```py
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas
import panel as pn
pn.extension()

# create sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range(start='01-01-2020', end='31-12-2020'),
    'status': np.random.choice(['confirmed', 'bedridden', 'recovered'], 366),
    'status2': np.random.choice(['A', 'B', 'C'], 366),
    'value': np.random.rand(366) * 100
})

types = ['confirmed', 'bedridden', 'recovered']

# you need to return your plot to get the interaction
def plot_heatmap(chosen_type):
    df_selected = df[df['status']==chosen_type]
    # hvplot is handy for creating interactive plots
    heatmap = df_selected.hvplot.heatmap(x='date', y='status2', C='value')
    return heatmap

# show your interactive plot with dropdown   
pn.interact(plot_heatmap, chosen_type=types)
```

As a sidenote, with [hvplot](https://hvplot.holoviz.org/user_guide/Introduction.html) you wouldn't need all this extra code to get a decent interactive heatmap with dropdown. You could just do:

```py
df.hvplot.heatmap(x='status2', y='date', C='value', groupby='status')
```

**More info on pn.interact():**
https://panel.holoviz.org/getting_started/index.html

**Resulting interactive plot with dropdown:**
[image: interactive heatmap with dropdown]